# 3.5: append an object without its associated objects?

Tags: objects, append

When I want to append in a single object from another file, all its related objects come in too. An old post says that "unchecking Localize All" is supposed to fix it but in all the years I've been using Blender this has never worked for me.

Comment: Hi :). Can't test it right now, but perhaps appending the *mesh* instead of the whole object could work.

Comment: I had that thought too: base mesh or curve, but unfortunately it still brings in all the related objects- even objects that I tried to manually sever ties to!